# Angular 4 router loses params when refreshing page

Tags: angular, router, angular-router

When i am using router link, the router finds the page and renders it
but when i am trying to refresh the page or re enter from the url, it fails and gives me this error:

**Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'project'**

I've searched a lot before asking here but couldn't find an answer.

The link i am using:
http://localhost:4200/#/project/5

This is my router configuration:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: UserHomepageComponent },
    { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent },
    { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
    { path: 'userHomepage', component: UserHomepageComponent },
    { path: 'project/:project', component: ProjectComponent }
];
```

the link that does work:

```
<div [routerLink]="['/project/', project.id ]" class="project" *ngFor="let project of projects">
    <div class="project-name">{{project.id}} - {{project.description}}</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be just

```
<div [routerLink]="['/project', project.id ]" class="project" *ngFor="let project of projects"> <div class="project-name">{{project.id}} - {{project.description}}</div> </div>
```

Also i see that you have # in the path, so when you refresh it may cannot find the matching routes!

change your app.module without these,

**`{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}`**

Comment: tried you suggestion, remove the extra /...but it is still not working

Comment: check how does the url look like and post here

Comment: were you able to fix it

Comment: no, still not working? is it a known bug or i am doing something wrong?